# When I run the code down below it prints "4294967295" and not '-1', Why?

Tags: c++

So I made this code for a school exercise and When i Run this code i would like it to show -1, but instead it shows 4294967295 and i don't understand why.

```
#include <iostream>

class Integer
{
    unsigned i;
    bool positive;

public:
    Integer(unsigned i, bool positive = true)
        : i(i)
        , positive(positive)
    {
    }

    Integer operator+(const Integer a) const
    {
        if (positive && a.positive)
            return Integer(i + a.i);
        else if (positive && !a.positive)
            return Integer(i - a.i);
        else if (!positive && a.positive)
            return Integer(a.i - i);
        else
            return Integer(-i - a.i);
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Integer& i)
    {
        if (!i.positive)
            out << "-";
        out << i.i;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Integer a1(2u);
    Integer a2(3u, false);

    std::cout << a2 + a1 << std::endl;
}
```

And when i run it, it shows :

```
4294967295
```

Comment: Why should it print -1?

Comment: `4294967295` is equivalent to an unsigned 32-bit integer with all bits set to `1`. Which is the same as the two's complement representation of `-1`. ***If*** the value was signed, which it isn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `+` operator is not designed correctly.  In every case, you omit the second argument to the constructor of Integer (whose name is `positive`), so every integer you make there will have `positive` set to true, and hence `(a1+a2)` is always positive (i.e. `positive` is true).

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
else if (positive && !a.positive )
    return Integer(i-a.i);
```

Think about what happens if a.i is > i:

i - a.i will not become something negative because its unsigned and unsigned values cannot be negative. Same is true for the third case
You will get an integer overflow and the number wraps back around to 2^32-1 for -1.

Also you never set the positive flag to false in any of the cases.

So in case your a.i is > i and a.i is negative you should instead set i to a.i-i and the positive flag to false.

Comment: Almost correct, but there is no integer overflow.